# How to connect keycloak with react? No routes matched location "/undefined/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html"

Tags: reactjs, keycloak-rest-api

Following `https://scalac.io/blog/user-authentication-keycloak-1/` I have made realm and put json config in react app. But when required it does not initialize giving following error:

```
"No routes matched location "/undefined/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html"
```

keyclock.js:

```
{
  "realm": "ReactTaskApp",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "react-client",
  "clientId": "react-client",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team and I encountered the same problem, and figured out that when passing config to `keycloak.js`, all attribute names should be camelCased! Another thing is (if I remember correctly) that instead of `authServerUrl` you should pass only `url` as attribute name.
With that saying:

```
{
  "realm": "ReactTaskApp",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "sslRequired": "external",
  "resource": "react-client",
  "clientId": "react-client",
  "publicClient": true,
  "confidentialPort": 0
}
```

Comment: It worked. __ But now I am getting this error: `keycloak.mjs:776  POST http://localhost:8080/realms/ReactTaskApp/protocol/openid-connect/token 401 (Unauthorized)` resource:1 
      
       Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Any help on this please?

Comment: You need to ask for access token and attach it to each request as ‘Bearer {token}’

Comment: This solves a lot of people's issues with reloading and the app not working.
Thanks!

Comment: Still getting this error, I am directly redirecting from my aaplication to keycloak by replacing url. On successful redirect back to my application with session_state and code, in console I can see this error is triggered continuously. @Andy